# Django ORM more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: python, django, django-orm

My Subquery behaves differently on different machines.
Subquery looks like:

```
Sale.objects.filter(object_id=OuterRef("id"), is_canceled=False)
.values("object")
.annotate(total_amount=Coalesce(Sum("amount"), 0))
.values("total_amount")
```

On my local machine I have 3 Sale instances and the result of the query is:

```
<QuerySet [{'object': 1, 'total_amount': 210}]>
```

On my dev machine I have 2 Sale instances and the result of a call looks like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'object': 100, 'total_amount': 20}, {'object': 100, 'total_amount': 10}]>
```

I checked the query Django ORM generates in both cases and it looks the same

```
SELECT "object_sale"."object_id", COALESCE(SUM("object_sale"."amount"), 0) AS "total_amount"
FROM "object_sale" 
WHERE ("object_sale"."object_id" = 1) 
GROUP BY "object_sale"."object_id", "object_sale"."price" 
ORDER BY "object_sale"."price" ASC
```

Comment: Where is that `"object_sale"."price"` coming from in the group by and order by?

Comment: It's from `order_by`

Comment: But I don't see any `order_by` calls on the queryset? Or is it the default ordering?

Comment: Yeah, it's from default ordering on the model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can see in the query this part is what is the problem:

```
GROUP BY "object_sale"."object_id", "object_sale"."price" 
ORDER BY "object_sale"."price" ASC
```

Instead of simply grouping on `object_id` it is also grouping on `price` but this causes there to be multiple rows in the result, plus the result is also incorrect. Hence we don't want this ordering or grouping by `price`. This is caused by the default ordering of the model being on `price`, to solve this we can simply call `order_by` on the queryset without any arguments to remove the default ordering:

```
Sale.objects.filter(object_id=OuterRef("id"), is_canceled=False).order_by()
.values("object")
.annotate(total_amount=Coalesce(Sum("amount"), 0))
.values("total_amount")
```